# Good ASP.NET method for checking, reading and returning file contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, include, methods, return-value

I found a good way to check if a file exists and read the contents if it does, but for some reason I can't create a method out of it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(Object s, EventArgs e) {

        lblFunction.Text = mwbInclude("test.txt");
    }


    string mwbInclude(string fileName) {
        string inc = Server.MapPath("/extra/include/"  + Request["game"] +  "/" + fileName);
        string valinc;

        if(System.IO.File.Exists(inc))
        {
            valinc = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(inc);
        }

        return valinc;
    }
</script>
```

I wish I could provide more info, but the server this is on doesn't show any feedback on errors, just a 404 page.

Comment: wrap your code in a try/catch and on error Response.Write the exception information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
valinc = Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(inc));
```

should be

```
valinc = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(inc);
```

Comment: I overlooked that, indeed. But it still fails without it.

Comment: Please provide more info re "fails".

Comment: I wish I could, but it's a very closed system at work.
And I have to do this directly on production, it doesn't spew errors.

However, I "fixed" it by not using the function, but repeating the code each time. Not very neat, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting the `Text` property *and* calling `Response.Write`? Do you want to render the text as a label, or as the whole response?

Comment: Ah yes, of course, the Response.Write shouldn't be there. But even without it, it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 404, it's because your page isn't being found, not because there's a problem with the script itself. Have you tried ripping out all of the code and just sticking in some HTML tags as a sanity check?